# No ASP.NET control intellisense in Win2K8 server (not R2) x64, VS2008 SP1

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, intellisense

This is a new install of Visual Studio 2008 SP1 on Windows 2008 (original) SP1.  I have opened up projects I have previously had intellisense in in VS2008 on different machines, but I don't get intellisense for any asp: server control.

I have intellisense for HTML markup, and I have it for the vsdoc version of jQuery on the same page that I *don't* have it for any asp:*control* named control.  I have this standard tag definition in web.config:

I have tried ScottGu's hotfix rollup and many hours of things to get it to work.  No Google, Bing or StackOverflow search has shown me anyone with exactly the same problem.  Does anyone have any suggestions for what to try to get intellisense to work for asp controls?

Comment: Does it work in a brand new/empty project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to reset the settings, also try running VS in safemode:

devenv.exe /safemode (http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this problem after delete the C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0 folder

Answer (score 0):

You might have followed this during you search. If not have a look at 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsdebug/thread/383dc775-5577-4cfd-80c8-b21c85a93fdb

Answer (score 0):

Actually we had the same issue before and I'm not actually suggesting to do the same thing but on my end I just get frustrated after a series of installation on the updates and after a bunch of research nothing happened. So what I did, I tried to do a system restore back to the first day that I have installed my vs2008 and then after system restore I tried to open vs2008 and still nothing so I uninstalled it after that run a registry cleaner something like the CCleaner and the install the vs2008 again and it worked. The next thing I did was to create a restoration point making sure that I have a working vs2008 installed with a specific restoration point just in case it bugs me out again. Sounds crazy and so much waste of time but somehow if you also get frustrated sometimes you get to think of just reinstalling it. I'm not sure if I did the right thing but 1 thing for sure I know, what I did gaved me the 100% solution to my problem. :))